# react native react-navigation V2 Not showing Screen header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I used React navigation in react native app recently i update react-navigation 1.* to 2.* now Screen headers are not showing after I use **createBottomTabNavigator**

this is the code that I have in my HomeScreen

```
static navigationOptions =({navigation})=> {


return {
  headerTitle: <Logo type="default_logo" />,
  headerTitleStyle: { alignItems: "center" },
  headerStyle: {
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  headerLeft: (
    <ClickableIcon
      source={NotificationInactive}
      height={35}
      width={35}
      onIconPressed={() => alert("Notifications Clicked")}
    />
  ),
  headerRight: (
    <ClickableIcon
      height={35}
      width={35}
      source={AddNewUserInactive}
      onIconPressed={() => alert("Add New Clicked")}
    />
  )
}
```

}

Comment: The way navigationOptions merge with screen navigationOptions has changed in v2.0.0. So, check this link for the changes https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#docsNav

Comment: I think it is same in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535654/react-native-tab-navigation-screen-title-not-showing/50542837#50542837

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
{
            stack: {
                children: [
                    {
                        component: {
                            name: 'demoApplication.NewsListScreen',  //tab component
                        }
                    }
                ],
                options: {           // try options for topbar and bottom tabs       
                    bottomTab: {
                        text: 'Users',
                        icon: require('../../assets/images/two.png')
                    },
                    topBar: {
                        drawBehind: false,
                        background: {
                            color: 'transparent'
                        },
                        title: {    // Title can be used as text or component
                            component: {
                                id: "LogoComponent",
                                name: 'app.LogoComponent',
                                alignment: 'center'
                            }
                            // text:"title"
                        },
                        leftButtons: [{
                            icon: require("../../assets/images/one.png"),
                            id: "left",
                            enabled: true,
                            buttonColor: "green",
                            color:"red",
                            disableIconTint: true,
                        }],
                        rightButtons: [{
                            icon: require("../../assets/images/two.png"),
                            id: 'right',
                            enabled: true,
                            buttonColor: "#green",
                            color:"red",
                            disableIconTint: true,
                        }]
                    }
                } 
            }
          }
```